# Lazy Evaluation in Bash

Tags: bash, lazy-evaluation

Is there more elegant way of doing lazy evaluation than the following:

```
pattern='$x and $y'
x=1
y=2
eval "echo $pattern"
```

results:

```
1 and 2
```

It works but `eval "echo ..."` just feels sloppy and may be insecure in some way.  Is there a better way to do this in Bash?

Comment: I'm curious why you want to do this or what it is you're actually trying to accomplish. Sometimes `eval` is the right or only way to go, but there are also special features of `declare` and `printf` that might be useful. And there may be other ways to accomplish what you're after.

Comment: I have a bash script that I want to be configurable.  I want the user to have the ability to specify a "pattern".  Later, some variables in the pattern will be replaced with activities run by the script (SQL queries, SOAP calls, and other in-house utilities) and passed to another command-line program.  I'm somewhat new to Bash and something about this approach just feels wrong.  Thanks for asking more details.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the command [envsubst](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/envsubst-Invocation.html) from [gettext](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/), for example:

```
$ pattern='x=$x and y=$y'
$ x=1 y=2 envsubst <<< $pattern
x=1 and y=2
```

Comment: I think the security stuff is a bit paranoid for this case.  I like the extra quotes.

Answer (score 8):

One safe possibility is to use a function:

```
expand_pattern() {
    pattern="$x and $y"
}
```

That's all. Then use as follows:

```
x=1 y=1
expand_pattern
echo "$pattern"
```

You can even use `x` and `y` as environment variables (so that they are not set in the main scope):

```
x=1 y=1 expand_pattern
echo "$pattern"
```

Comment: This is the answer I was going to write if it hadn't already been here. (Then again, I only spotted this question at all by virtue of the answer having been added, bouncing it back to the front page). :)

Answer (score 0):

You're right, `eval` is a security risk in this case. Here is one possible approach:

```
pattern='The $a is $b when the $z is $x $c $g.'    # simulated input from user (use "read")
unset results
for word in $pattern
do
    case $word in
        \$a)
            results+=($(some_command))   # add output of some_command to array (output is "werewolf"
            ;;
        \$b)
            results+=($(echo "active"))
            ;;
        \$c)
            results+=($(echo "and"))
            ;;
        \$g)
            results+=($(echo "the sky is clear"))
            ;;
        \$x)
            results+=($(echo "full"))
            ;;
        \$z)
            results+=($(echo "moon"))
            ;;
          *)
            do_something    # count the non-vars, do a no-op, twiddle thumbs
            # perhaps even sanitize %placeholders, terminal control characters, other unwanted stuff that the user might try to slip in
            ;;
    esac
done
pattern=${pattern//\$[abcgxz]/%s}    # replace the vars with printf string placeholders
printf "$pattern\n" "${results[@]}"  # output the values of the vars using the pattern
printf -v sentence "$pattern\n" "${results[@]}"  # put it into a variable called "sentence" instead of actually printing it
```

The output would be "The werewolf is active when the moon is full and the sky is clear." The very same program, if the pattern is 'The $x $z is out $c $g, so the $a must be $b.' then the output would be "The full moon is out and the sky is clear, so the werewolf must be active."

Comment: The answer matches the example of the question. But it does not seem to be very useful for anything more complicated that basic string replacements. If I try to follow this approach, I have to write a Bash interpreter in Bash.

Comment: My answer is a way to insulate the script from the untrusted input of a user. It's based on the OP's comment attached to the question in response to my query.